# MySQL, error creating system tablespace ibdata1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a MySQL database (version 5.6.21-log) which I wanted to reset.

I have erased the database folder (where I had my tables), and also the ibdata1 (the system tablespace).

The problem is that when I restart the server I get this error:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file 
/myqdata/myserver01/data/ibdata1
```

It looks like MySQL is not able to create the system tablespace correctly. I am not finding many references to this issue, any idea on how to

Comment: provide details of my.cnf file

Comment: Perhaps you needed to remove the two iblog files, too.